# Use of crontab, kill and trap

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I'm learning `crontab` command, and I'm doing some tries.

I edited the default crontab file with the command `crontab -e`, and I want to put a line that every minute send a SIGUSR1 to the current shell process (*pid 14515*), and then, after received the signal, print a default message to stdout.

I add this line:

```
1 * * * * kill -USR1 14515 | trap "echo Sigusr1 received" SIGUSR1
```

But after a minute I see nothing printed on my terminal.
What's wrong? Can I use other way to do this thing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/cron-crontab-execute-a-script-every-minute-and-another-one-every-24-hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues with this. First, anything in the crontab file is run in the background, not in your terminal. So any "echo" in there won't be seen (unless it's sent to you in an email).

Try leaving the kill there (I'm sure you're aware that it'll change if you log out), but move the 'trap' to your shell.

Also, your line, as it's written, will only run on the first minute of every hour (2:01, 3:01, etc). If you want something to run every minute, do:

```
 * * * * * kill -USR1 PID
```

Comment: Oh yes! Now it works!! Thank you for the suggest.